# Let $X_i$ be i.i.d discrete random variables and $M = max_i(X_i)$. Find $\mathbb{P}(M = m)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

A known approach for a similar problem, $\mathbb{P}(M \le m)$, can be formulated as

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(M \le m) = \prod_{i}\mathbb{P}(X_i \le m)
\end{eqnarray}

However, by dealing with a specific value, there can be multiple ways of achieving the desired outcome. For instance, let $i = \{{ 1, 2\}}$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(M = m) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = m;\; X_2 < m) \; \cup \;\mathbb{P}(X_1 < m;\; X_2 = m)\; \cup \;\mathbb{P}(X_1 = m;\; X_2 = m)
\end{eqnarray}

In order to overcome the necessity of counting for all the possible combinations, I thought about considering the 'range approach', as

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(M = m) &=& 1 - \mathbb{P}(M < m) - \mathbb{P}(M > m) \\
&=& 1 - \prod_{i}\mathbb{P}(X_i < m) - \prod_{i}\mathbb{P}(X_i > m)
\end{eqnarray}

I was wondering if there is any mistake in this approach to tackle the original problem. If not, what would be other options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Probability theory](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) is [about the measure-theoretic foundations](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8587/290189) of stochastics.  The tag ([tag:probability-theory]) should be used for questions concerning this subject, not for questions about calculating a specific probability.  Use ([tag:probability]) instead, see also [meta](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1686/290189).

Comment: As $X_i$'s are discrete, so as $M$.  When you know how to calculate $P(M \le m)$, you also know how to calculate it's complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first equality is correct. However:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(M = m) &=& 1 - \mathbb{P}(M < m) - \mathbb{P}(M > m) \\
&=& 1 - \prod_{i}\mathbb{P}(X_i < m) - (1-\prod_{i}\mathbb{P}(X_i \leq m))\\
&=&\prod_{i}\mathbb{P}(X_i \leq m))-\prod_{i}\mathbb{P}(X_i < m).
\end{eqnarray}

Otherwise you can use this approach.

Comment: In other words, the problem is that $\mathbb P(M>m)$ cannot be factored as $\prod_i \mathbb P(X_i > m)$, since it takes only *one* $X_i > m$ to have $M>m$, not all of them.